# application unfortunately after change the package name

Tags: java, android, android-layout

i try to change my package name for my app , when run the app  application unfortunately.

use android studio , i change package name manifest and gradle. thank you

use android studio , i change package name manifest and gradle. thank you

use android studio , i change package name manifest and gradle. thank you

```
02/05 03:01:55: Launching app
$ adb push C:\Users\msi\Desktop\Bukhary\Bukhary\app\build\outputs\apk\app-debug.apk /data/local/tmp/com.guideDandy.Dungeonguideitem
$ adb shell pm install -r "/data/local/tmp/com.guideDandy.Dungeonguideitem"
    pkg: /data/local/tmp/com.guideDandy.Dungeonguideitem
Success


$ adb shell am start -n "com.guideDandy.Dungeonguideitem/com.guideDandy.Dungeonguideitem.Splash_Activity" -a android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER
Connected to process 996 on device Nexus_5_API_16_kitkat [emulator-5556]
E/Trace: error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.view.Window$Callback.onProvideKeyboardShortcuts, referenced from method android.support.v7.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.onProvideKeyboardShortcuts
W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve interface method 19844: Landroid/view/Window$Callback;.onProvideKeyboardShortcuts (Ljava/util/List;Landroid/view/Menu;I)V
D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x72 at 0x0002
W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature (Landroid/view/SearchEvent;)
I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.view.Window$Callback.onSearchRequested, referenced from method android.support.v7.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.onSearchRequested
W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve interface method 19846: Landroid/view/Window$Callback;.onSearchRequested (Landroid/view/SearchEvent;)Z
D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x72 at 0x0002
I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.view.Window$Callback.onWindowStartingActionMode, referenced from method android.support.v7.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.onWindowStartingActionMode
W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve interface method 19850: Landroid/view/Window$Callback;.onWindowStartingActionMode (Landroid/view/ActionMode$Callback;I)Landroid/view/ActionMode;
D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x72 at 0x0002
I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.content.res.TypedArray.getChangingConfigurations, referenced from method android.support.v7.widget.TintTypedArray.getChangingConfigurations
W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 468: Landroid/content/res/TypedArray;.getChangingConfigurations ()I
D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0002
I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.content.res.TypedArray.getType, referenced from method android.support.v7.widget.TintTypedArray.getType
W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 490: Landroid/content/res/TypedArray;.getType (I)I
D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0008
I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable, referenced from method android.support.v7.widget.ResourcesWrapper.getDrawable
W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 431: Landroid/content/res/Resources;.getDrawable (ILandroid/content/res/Resources$Theme;)Landroid/graphics/drawable/Drawable;
D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0002
I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.content.res.Resources.getDrawableForDensity, referenced from method android.support.v7.widget.ResourcesWrapper.getDrawableForDensity
W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 433: Landroid/content/res/Resources;.getDrawableForDensity (IILandroid/content/res/Resources$Theme;)Landroid/graphics/drawable/Drawable;
D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0002
D/dalvikvm: GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 172K, 2% free 18820K/19143K, paused 31ms, total 37ms
I/dalvikvm-heap: Grow heap (frag case) to 19.482MB for 1048592-byte allocation
D/dalvikvm: GC_CONCURRENT freed 2K, 2% free 19841K/20231K, paused 22ms+36ms, total 68ms
D/dalvikvm: GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 0K, 2% free 19842K/20231K, paused 18ms, total 18ms
I/dalvikvm-heap: Grow heap (frag case) to 28.480MB for 9437200-byte allocation
D/dalvikvm: GC_CONCURRENT freed 0K, 2% free 29058K/29511K, paused 24ms+4ms, total 101ms
D/dalvikvm: WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 73ms
E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.graphics.drawable.RippleDrawable', referenced from method android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageHelper.hasOverlappingRendering
W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve instanceof 144 (Landroid/graphics/drawable/RippleDrawable;) in Landroid/support/v7/widget/AppCompatImageHelper;
D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x20 at 0x000c
D/libEGL: loaded /system/lib/egl/libEGL_emulation.so
D/libEGL: loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_emulation.so
D/libEGL: loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv2_emulation.so

          [ 02-05 02:02:03.069   996:  996 D/         ]
          HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0x2a119d68, tid 996
W/EGL_emulation: eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
D/OpenGLRenderer: Enabling debug mode 0
W/EGL_emulation: eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.view.ViewGroup.onRtlPropertiesChanged, referenced from method android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar.onRtlPropertiesChanged
W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 19740: Landroid/view/ViewGroup;.onRtlPropertiesChanged (I)V
D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6f at 0x0007
I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.widget.LinearLayout$LayoutParams.<init>, referenced from method android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout$LayoutParams.<init>
W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve direct method 20386: Landroid/widget/LinearLayout$LayoutParams;.<init> (Landroid/widget/LinearLayout$LayoutParams;)V
D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x70 at 0x0000
I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.widget.LinearLayout$LayoutParams.<init>, referenced from method android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout$LayoutParams.<init>
W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve direct method 20386: Landroid/widget/LinearLayout$LayoutParams;.<init> (Landroid/widget/LinearLayout$LayoutParams;)V
D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x70 at 0x0000
I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.content.Context.getColorStateList, referenced from method android.support.v7.content.res.AppCompatResources.getColorStateList
W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 280: Landroid/content/Context;.getColorStateList (I)Landroid/content/res/ColorStateList;
D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0006
D/dalvikvm: GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1225K, 5% free 28396K/29767K, paused 21ms, total 26ms
I/dalvikvm-heap: Grow heap (frag case) to 29.787MB for 2048016-byte allocation
D/dalvikvm: GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 2K, 5% free 30393K/31815K, paused 48ms, total 49ms
D/dalvikvm: GC_CONCURRENT freed 38K, 5% free 30355K/31815K, paused 22ms+4ms, total 60ms
D/dalvikvm: WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 4ms
D/dalvikvm: GC_FOR_ALLOC freed <1K, 5% free 30355K/31815K, paused 22ms, total 22ms
I/dalvikvm-heap: Grow heap (frag case) to 47.325MB for 18432016-byte allocation
D/dalvikvm: GC_CONCURRENT freed 0K, 4% free 48355K/49863K, paused 16ms+29ms, total 69ms
D/dalvikvm: WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 13ms
E/SQLiteLog: (1) no such table: Main_Titles
D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
W/dalvikvm: threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a122a0)
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                  java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resume activity {com.guideDandy.Dungeonguideitem/com.guideDandy.Dungeonguideitem.MainActivity}: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: Main_Titles (code 1): , while compiling: select * from Main_Titles
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2575)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2603)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2089)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195)
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
                      at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
                   Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: Main_Titles (code 1): , while compiling: select * from Main_Titles
                      at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
                      at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:882)
                      at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:493)
                      at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
                      at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:58)
                      at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQuery.<init>(SQLiteQuery.java:37)
                      at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.query(SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.java:44)
                      at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQueryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1314)
                      at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQuery(SQLiteDatabase.java:1253)
                      at com.guideDandy.Dungeonguideitem.DatabaseHelper.get_All_Main_Titles(DatabaseHelper.java:48)
                      at com.guideDandy.Dungeonguideitem.MainActivity.import_Main_listIndex(MainActivity.java:254)
                      at com.guideDandy.Dungeonguideitem.MainActivity.onResume(MainActivity.java:265)
                      at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnResume(Instrumentation.java:1184)
                      at android.app.Activity.performResume(Activity.java:5082)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2565)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2603) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2089) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195) 
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745) 
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786) 
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553) 
                      at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: the error stated that ```Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: Main_Titles (code 1): , while compiling: select * from Main_Titles```.. check this

Answer (score 0):

It is a bit hard understanding what you want to do but...

Pakage name changes can be tricky, especially if your app is complex.

Try refreshing your build, and ensuring you have everything linking to the right package, such as on the top of all java files. 
Sometimes the easiest way, I have found to change a pakage name is to recreate your app with the new name, then simply copy and paste your existing xml/java files over to the new app(making sure you change the pakage name on each one) then rebuild the gradle.

In addition:
I never advise modification to a Gradle file by hand.